# Linux: nslookup and dig resolve $HOSTNAME, but ping doesn't

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, linux-networking, ping, dnsmasq

In our private network we have a [Consul](https://consul.io/) service discovery server (`10.241.232.14`) that provides a DNS interface (port `8600`). We would like to set our common DNS servers to forward some queries to the Consul in order to resolve the hostnames of *dockerized* services into the names of physical servers they are running on.

So we have Ubuntu 14.10 on our desktops with `dnsmasq` preinstalled. We added a file into `/etc/dnsmasq.d` providing the information about the Consul's private DNS (please note that there are some other system-wise DNS servers that are configured by DHCP: local `dnsmasq` instance should be aware of all of them too):

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/10-consul 
server=/service.search.km./10.241.232.14#8600
```

After `dnsmasq`'s restart **we are able to perform name lookups** with such standard tools as `dig`, `nslookup` or `host`:

```
$ host jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km
jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km is an alias for mailtest-4.dev.search.km.

$ nslookup jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km   canonical name = mailtest-4.dev.search.km.

$ dig @localhost jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-4.3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> @localhost jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32618
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km. 0 IN CNAME mailtest-4.dev.search.km.

;; Query time: 25 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 23 19:49:45 MSK 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 130
```

But for a some reason **we cannot ping or connect** to this address:

```
$ ping jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km
ping: unknown host jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km

$ curl http://jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km:8082
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km
```

Here are our configs:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search int.pv.km srv.pv.km dev.ix.km search.km ix.km srv.search.km

$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

# hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

I've seen several similair questions over here, but none of them corresponds directly to our problem. Any help will be appreciated.

**FYI:** I've noticed that `ping` writes to the descriptor truncated hostname `jenkins-deb-builder` instead of `jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km`... What's going on here?

```
$ strace ping jenkins-deb-builder.service.consul 
...
stat("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=239, ...}) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "\364\25\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 52, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 52
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [127])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "\364\25\201\203\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 127
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "\220P\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 62, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 62
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [112])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "\220P\205\203\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 112
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "\354\274\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 62, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 62
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [118])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "\354\274\205\203\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 118
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "\211\222\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 62, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 62
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [112])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "\211\222\205\203\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 112
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "\2077\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 62, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 62
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [112])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "\2077\205\203\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 112
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "\257b\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 58, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 58
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [108])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "\257b\205\203\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 108
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(3, "L5\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 66, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 66
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [116])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "L5\205\203\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\23jenkins-deb-builder"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 116
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "ping: unknown host jenkins-deb-b"..., 54ping: unknown host jenkins-deb-builder.service.consul
) = 54
exit_group(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

`ping` and `curl` are trying to get an actual IP address but the answer to the resolution jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km is a CNAME ( mailtest-4.dev.search.km ) and that canonical name doesn't resolve to an IP address, that's why those tools cannot get an IP address.

If Consul is able to resolve mailtest-4.dev.search.km then maybe you should modify your dnsmasq to be something like:

```
server=/search.km./10.241.232.14#8600
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by pablo-martinez, your nslookup and dig responses do not include IP addresses. This suggests that your DNS server has a `CNAME` record for jenkins-deb-builder.service.search.km but no `A` record for mailtest-4.dev.search.km.

Adding the corresponding `A` record to your DNS server should resolve the problem.